# Преферанс (4 туза)

Tags: c++

При игре в преферанс используется колода в 42 карты (в ней 4 туза). По 10 карт
раздается четырём игрокам и две карты откладываются в прикуп. Каждый игрок похвастал,
сколько у него тузов. Определите, сколько игроков заведомо солгали.
Например, они сказали 1, 1, 1, 2. Следовательно, заведомо солгал один игрок. (Какие-то трое могли сказать правду, но все четверо правду сказать не могли, так как тузов всего 4). Вводятся 4 числа в диапазоне от 0 до 9. Требуется вывести минимальное количество игроков, которые солгали. Если все могли сказать правду - вывести 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    int x[4];
    if ((a+b+c+d)<=4) {
        cout << '0';
        return 0;}
    x[0]=a;
    x[1]=b;
    x[2]=c;
    x[3]=d;
     int temp; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 - i ; j++) {
            if (x[j] > x[j + 1]) {
                temp = x[j];
                x[j] = x[j + 1];
                x[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
        if ((x[0]+x[1]+x[2]) <=4) {
        cout << '1';
        return 0;}
        if ((x[0]+x[1]) <= 4) {
        cout << '2';
        return 0;}
        if (x[0]==4) {
        cout << '3';
        return 0;}
        if (x[0]>4) {
        cout << '4';
        return 0;}    
}
```

Вот мой код. Сначала я их ставлю в порядке возрастания а после проверяю, сколько игроков могли солгать. Вроде рассмотрел все случаи, потестил программу, а на 100 баллов она не заходит. Можете указать на мою ошибку, пожалуйста?

Comment: А дайте URL проверяющей системы, интересно попробовать...

Comment: Это учебная система, увы, на неё простой регистрацией не попасть.

Comment: интересно прикуп сам сказал сколько у него тузов или сдающему надо дать по мозгам за то что посмотрел... а по делу: ты не проверяешь, может ли в прикупе из двух карт оказаться 3 туза...

Comment: Извините, не совсем понял, как в двух картах могут уместиться 3 туза?

Comment: Мы же рассматриваем вариант где ответ - именно минимальное количество солгавших игроков, то есть, максимально возможное количество ходовых тузов - а это 4, поэтому в прикупе в этой задаче должно быть 0 тузов.

Comment: представим, что игроки сказали так: `4 1 1 1`, тогда ваш вывод будет `3`, а должен быть `1` (солгал тот, кто сказал, что у него `4`)

Comment: Моя программа выводит 1, а не 3.

Comment: @Kritiy, по условию в прикупе всего 2 карты, но ты не проверяешь, что последний назвал число ≤2. А ещё ты не проверяешь, что в сумме получилось 4 туза т.е. при условии `0 0 0 0` кто-то тоже точно соврал... ЗЫ: если ожидаешь ответа в комментариях, то упоминай имя через собаку...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 1):

Можно "тупо" перебрать возможные сочетания их "показаний":

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool NextSet(int *indexes, int n, int m){
    for (int i = m-1; i>=0; --i)
        if (indexes[i] < n-m+i+1){
            ++indexes[i];
            for (int j = i+1; j<m; ++j)
                indexes[j] = indexes[j-1] + 1;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

int sum(int *x, int *indexes, int n){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        s += x[indexes[i]];
    return s;
}

int main(){
    const int n=4;
    int *indexes = new int[n];
    int *x = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        cin >> x[i];

    for(int m = n; m>0; --m){
        for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
            indexes[i] = i;

        while(NextSet(indexes, n, m))
            if(sum(x, indexes, m) <= n){
                cout << n-m << '\n';
                return 0;
            }
    }
    delete []x;
    delete []indexes;
    return 0;
}
```